# Can I open the macOS preview app with a pdf open and automatically search for a string

Tags: macos, pdf, preview.app

I'd like to open the preview app with a pdf from a command line and make it search for a term an display the found term tight away.

I thought about something like this:

```
open xyz.pdf --args -f term
```

But this of course doesn't work.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Preview app doesn't have that kind of command line support. You could potentially use the automator app to complete this task.

To search for text in a pdf within terminal you could use
`grep -a search_term xyz.pdf`

Edit 1:

Here is an image of the automator workflow I used to search for the phrase "core".

[image: Automator PDF Search Workflow]

1. Open automator, create "New Document" and select "Application".
2. Search for actions (top left) "Ask for Finder Items" and "Open Finder Items"
3. Drag actions into the workflow on the right and select "Preview.app" for the Open Finder Items action
4. Record yourself searching preview for the phrase you desire.
5. Stop your record session.
6. Clean up your record session "Watch Me Do" Events since it captured you switching windows and possibly clicking around.
7. Save and click Run.

You can run the automator app from the CLI, but you will still have to select your file after the app starts.

Note: You can probably speed things up by adjusting the playback speed setting in Watch Me Do.

Comment: Thanks, but I need it displayed on preview's or another app's window.

Answer (score 0):

One way of searching a pdf using the command line is to convert the content of the pdf to text first.

The [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) package manager includes the following packages that can help you achieve this task quickly and efficiently without lots of brittle GUI automation:

1. [**pdfsandwich**](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/pdfsandwich#default): converts documents into text processable PDF text. Use this if your PDFs are images of text. E.g. scanned documents
2. **pdftotext**: extracts the text part of the document from the PDF file. Then you can *grep* the output

Once you have installed these, try them out on an an example pdf:

```
pdfsandwich example.pdf output.pdf
pdftotext output.pdf - | grep *keyword*
```

This will convert the PDF then you can pipe all the text found within the document through the *grep* utility. The grep utility is very powerful and will allow you to do a lot more than search for a simple character string (to find out more, try: `man grep`).